# Understanding QGIS reference frame issue?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I just changed my project coordinate reference frame to WGS 84 EPSG:4326. Additionally, I set the coordinate reference frame for each layer to EPSG:4326-WGS 84. However, the two layers don't line up. There appears to be some kind of vertical shift going on. Any ideas on what could be causing this discrepancy in their vertical position? In my second image I added the 'OpenStreetMap' layer and changed it's coordinate reference to WGS84, and as you can tell my layers are not lining up with Oklahoma.

How to I make them line up with where they should be?

[image: Vertical shift in layers]

[image]

Comment: You probably change the CRS in the layer properties, if so revert to the original one (if you remember it, if not start a new project) and let QGIS handle the reprojection

Comment: That seems to be exactly what I did. I didn't realize I wasn't suppose to change it in the layer properties. Thanks :) So to change the CRS I should I only change it in the 'Project Properties' and not for individual layers?

Comment: If you want to reproject a layer you need to choose `save as...` and create a new file. Simply changing the layers CRS does not reproject it! But QGIS supports on the fly projection, so if you only want to visualize a layer there is no need to reproject it.